# "Permission denied," when trying "ssh -T git@github.com"

Tags: github, ssh

i am trying to configure my git to deploy my hexo blog on github.

Firstly,I
`git config --global user.name "my github username"`
`git config --global user.email "my github registration email"`

Then,I use `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C 'my github registration email` to generate ssh key and add it to my github authentication keys.

But when I type command `ssh -T git@github.com`,the git bash shows:

```
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:rEmlJenVMSL5GVemS*********************.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com's password:
```

I tried input my github password,but it shows `Permission denied, please try again.`immediately.
After trying three times,it shows `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).`

My OS is windows 10.

How can i slove this?

Comment: This isn't a *Git* issue at this point, it's just ssh-and-GitHub. Something's gone wrong with your RSA key, but exactly what is not clear here. Use `ssh -Tv git@github.com` (and/or add more `-v` options / letters to this) to have ssh print more information, then look up what to do with the extra information. See the GitHub help pages too, which are pretty extensive.

Comment: @torek - `-vT` will be enought for starting debug

Answer (score 1):

First, the `user.name`/`email` setting has nothing to do with how GitHub authenticate you. It only matters for *local* commit authorship.

Second, the missing step in your process is the copy of the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (the *public* key) to your [GitHub settings SSH page](https://github.com/settings/keys).
That will allow GitHub to identify you as your GitHub account. See "[Adding a new SSH key to your GitHub account](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)".